# Generating distance from each address point on map to nearest fire hydrant using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, closest-facility

I am attempting to measure the distance between one set of points (Address point data) to the closest point from another set of points (Fire hydrants).

When I perform Closest Facility Analysis only a few routes between points show up (and it is not even the closest fire hydrant to that address point).

What am I doing wrong that is preventing me from generating a distance from each address point on my map to the nearest fire hydrant?

Is this a problem with adding the data to the Incidents/ Facilities - what can I do to mitigate/ solve this problem?

A majority of the time it says that it was unable to locate the facility

[image: Here is a screenshot after performing Closest Facility on a selection of the points. Ultimately I need one route per address point so I can tell how long in feet it is to the nearest fire hydrant.]

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 and have a feature dataset containing all of the feature classes I am using. I can convert to shapefiles if needed.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and edit your question to include what software you are using, what workflows you tried, etc. Are you using shapefiles or a geodatabase? Plus you are asking multiple questions. Please edit to only ask one.

Comment: I have removed your additional question about Geometric networks - I do not believe these will be useful in your situation.  Network Analyst is the right tool for what you are trying to do.